# Menu is sometimes getting screwed up in wordpress elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, elementor

It happens sometimes, on some browesers, for example now it appears only on firefox. is this common bug or i did something wrong?

[image: menu][image: that's how menu supposed to look like]